# C# app and Android app communication over Internet (Server)

Tags: java, c#, android, server

I am trying to make an app like Spotify (just for fun and practice), and I am at the phase to implement the remote control the phone app controlling the desktop app.
I already made a version that's using sockets, a local server, but that's not the "full package" as I can't use it when I'm not on the same network, so I was wondering if any of you have an idea on how to start and online server for that. The Android app sending a stop request to the server and then the PC app gets the request, any idea or anything that can help me start would be great (I don't need users so far just the apps to communicate with each other through the online server).

Comment: use android socket <--> server socket <-> desktop socket. So just put the serve in the middle and transport all what one client says to another client through second socket

Comment: So for that I need to have an online server with javascripts? Like this site does https://websocket.org/echo.html  ? or I can do something else?

Comment: you don't need any javascripts, but you do need the server

Comment: So I host a server online, what does it need to have on it? What script or what program,how do i send the message over and receive it?

Comment: you need to develop that program. It should accept 2 socket connections from 2 clients, and pass all the data from one to another and vice versa